# How to edit a JSON file in QT QML

Tags: json, qt, qml

I am new to QT, QML and JSON. I am trying to write a simple program that saves data into a JSON file. The programs has 3 files:

- main.qml  has 2 text input fields and 1 button that calls a function in script.js
- storage.json  {"sets":[{object Object},{object Object}]}
- script.js holds this function:

  ```
  function insertNewSet (name, description){

  var newSet = {
      setName: "name",
      setDescription: "description",
      setInput: []
  }

  var newJson = JSON.stringify(newSet);

  }
  ```

name and description come from the input fields in main.qml

How can the variable newSet be inserted as a third object in newSet?

example: {"sets":[{object Object},{object Object},{object Object}]}

Comment: did you mean "How can the variable newSet be inserted as a third object in 'sets' in storage.json?" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ' ' symbols to specify the properties.

These can be called up this way:

```
var newSet = {
       'setName': 'name',
       'setDescription': 'description',
       'setInput': []
}
var newJson = JSON.stringify(newSet['setName']+newSet['setDescription']+newSet['setInput']);
```

If you didn't think about it, maybe this page will help you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array